# How to select route records based on same bus

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table structure like:

```
+----+--------+-------------+------------+
| id | bus_id | board_point | drop_point |
+----+--------+-------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Toronto     | Toronto    |
|  2 |      1 | Toronto     | Ottawa     |
|  3 |      1 | Ottawa      | Montreal   |
|  4 |      1 | Montreal    | Quebec     |
| 10 |      3 | Whistler    | Banff      |
| 12 |      2 | Toronto     | Montreal   |
| 16 |      2 | Toronto     | Toronto    |
+----+--------+-------------+------------+
```

I would like to search board_point and drop_point if they have same bus_id. 
For example:

1. board_point = Toronto and drop_point = Quebec, the result is bus 1.
2. board_point = Toronto and drop_point = Montreal, the result is bus 1 and 2.
3. board_point = Toronto and drop_point = Banff, the result is no record because they are not in same bus.

If I only use where board_point = X or drop_point = Y, the result is not correct. My question is how to select * from route where board_point = X or drop_point = Y and they must in same bus_id.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You already asked this a few days ago? Edit your original question and show what you have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339452/select-records-based-on-other-column-has-same-value. Don't delete and recreate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
  SELECT bus_id,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN board_point = 'Toronto' THEN 1 END) as total_board,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN drop_point  = 'Quebec'  THEN 1 END) as total_drop
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY bus_id
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN board_point = 'Toronto' THEN 1 END)  > 0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN drop_point  = 'Quebec'  THEN 1 END)  > 0
```

Comment: shouldn't this part `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN board_point = 'Toronto' THEN 1 END)  > 0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN drop_point  = 'Quebec'  THEN 1 END)  > 0` be written like this `HAVING total_board  > 0
     AND total_drop > 0`

Comment: @PeterDarmis Maybe but `total_board` and  `total_drop` are just for debug, thery arent required for the answer. So if OP removed from the query this will still work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks for the comment but i know how to fix my queries to provide alternative and correct results ;) ... but +1 for a great example of `Aggregation` :)

Comment: @Iris - add the expected output to the question to make your question more clear.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch thanks, I think bus_id is enough to my question. Other part should be in PHP code.

Comment: @Iris - so how is it different to my answer a few days ago or the answer of Juan here?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch You are right,  different method but same logic. Btw Iris I should get the correct answer here. I post it firs and the answer are basically the same.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - yes I think this should be the solved answer. But something I don't understand is happening here :D - I never saw this on StackOverflow.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch That clanify in your profile has a github or something?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, you are both right, I just try to get 2 answers but only can get one. anyway, I change to you are correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.bus_id
from
   (
    select bus_id,drop_point
    from route
    where bus_id in (select distinct bus_id
                    from route
                    where board_point = 'Toronto'
                   )     
   )t
where t.drop_point = 'Quebec'
;
```

[New DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081f97/11/0)

Comment: Thanks, but where is the drop_point? I have 2 value is board_point and drop_point.

Comment: sorry I only found board_point='Toronto' condition where is the drop_point="Quebec" I didn't find.

Comment: Please try the edited query as well as Demo. I've added the condition and you can put different drop_point by replacing `Quebec` with the drop_point you want.

Comment: base on my example it is no problem, but please check I have a record is Toronto to Toronto, so only this part is incorrect. Juan Carlos Oropeza and Peter Darmis solution are better.

Comment: Ok. I've removed that condition. Check the edited answer,

Comment: My bad..By mistake I've used `id` INSTEAD of `bus_id`. Updated the answer as well as demo link. Totally wors now.

Comment: Glad to help. You can upvote it/mark it as answer if you think it's helpful.

Comment: sorry I already marked Juan Carlos Oropeza's answer. But you solution also is working properly for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) like in the example queries in order to give a positive value in case the `board_point` or `drop_point` have the specific value you seek.

> You need results when both conditions are met, meaning when both
>   `found_in_board`,`found_in_drop`, in the example queries below, are
>   positive

```
SELECT `busid`,
         SUM(IF(`board` = "Toronto",1,0)) AS `found_in_board`,
         SUM(IF(`drop` = "Montreal",1,0)) AS `found_in_drop`
  FROM `buses`
  GROUP BY `busid`
  HAVING `found_in_board`  > 0
     AND `found_in_drop`  > 0;

SELECT `busid`,
         SUM(IF(`board` = "Toronto",1,0)) AS `found_in_board`,
         SUM(IF(`drop` = "Banff",1,0)) AS `found_in_drop`
  FROM `buses`
  GROUP BY `busid`
  HAVING `found_in_board`  > 0
     AND `found_in_drop`  > 0;
```

You can check the output of the above queries in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d0fd/25)

Comment: `IF` isn't an aggregated function.

Comment: Your demo doesnt return the correct result. for Toronto - Montreal should be `bus_id = 1,2`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please check the edit. I ever mentioned in my answer that `IF` being an aggregated function.

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza and Peter Darmis, thanks I think you are both resolve my question